# RemoteApp sessions are disconnected when all RemoteApp windows and user-launched notification area icons are closed

Tags: remote-desktop-services, remoteapp, remote-desktop-gateway

My Remote App takes more than 20+ seconds to launch.

But by that time RemoteApp session is **disconnected** as no UI shown from App, if I launch another application like notepad which launches quickly I can see my previous application window.

From Microsoft reference I got [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/remote/remoteapp-sessions-disconnected#more-information) info, but this is for logout user after disconnect.

But I want to increase this time limit for disconnect.

Not able to find any Policy in Windows Server, any help?

Comment: There aren't any settings that have a granularity of less than one minute. If a session is disconnected, you should first determine why.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.